# удаляется элемент списка при создании через js

Tags: javascript

```
var btn = document.querySelector('.add');

function a() {

var title = document.getElementById('title').value;    //input.value

var list = document.querySelector('.list');            //<ul>
var li = document.createElement('li');                 //<li>
var createTitle = document.createElement('p');         //<p>

var tt = document.createTextNode(title);               //содержимое input.value

li.appendChild(tt);                                    //добавить содержимое в <li>
list.appendChild(li);                                  //<li> добавить в <ul>


 }

btn.addEventListener('click', a);
```

форма из которой берутся значения:

```
<div class="card addTask">
      <h2>Add a task</h2>
      <form action="">
        <input id="title" type="text" placeholder='Title'>
        <br>
        <textarea name="#" id="description" cols="#" rows="7" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="datepicker" placeholder="Due Date (dd/mm/yyyy)">
        <br>
        <button class="add">Add Task</button>
        <button class="clearData">Clear Data</button>
        <div class="delete">
          <p>Drag here to delete</p>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <button class="add">Add Task</button>
```

блок, в который значения прилетают:

```
<div class="card">
   <h2>Pending</h2>
   <ul class="list">
   </ul>
</div>
```

значение инпута пытаюсь всунуть в p, p в li, li в ul. в итоге при нажатии на кнопку btn элемент появляется в списке и в эту же секунду исчезает. не могу понять почему исчезает.

Comment: добавь разметку, к которой ты все это применяешь

Comment: event.preventDefault();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как у вас форма, то нужно отменить ее стандартное поведение
`event.preventDefault();`

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('.add');

function a(event) {
event.preventDefault();

var title = document.getElementById('title').value;    //input.value

var list = document.querySelector('.list');            //<ul>
var li = document.createElement('li');                 //<li>
var createTitle = document.createElement('p');         //<p>

var tt = document.createTextNode(title);               //содержимое input.value

li.appendChild(tt);                                    //добавить содержимое в <li>
list.appendChild(li);                                  //<li> добавить в <ul>


 }

btn.addEventListener('click', a);
```

```html
<div class="card addTask">
      <h2>Add a task</h2>
      <form action="">
        <input id="title" type="text" placeholder='Title'>
        <br>
        <textarea name="#" id="description" cols="#" rows="7" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="datepicker" placeholder="Due Date (dd/mm/yyyy)">
        <br>
        <button class="add">Add Task</button>
        <button class="clearData">Clear Data</button>
        <div class="delete">
          <p>Drag here to delete</p>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    
    <div class="card">
   <h2>Pending</h2>
   <ul class="list">
   </ul>
</div>
```